# How do I skip a patch when cherry-picking multiple?

Tags: git

I've begun cherry-picking with a command such as the following:

```
git cherry-pick A B C D
```

Lets say patches A and B have some merge conflicts but I eventually fix them all and `git cherry-pick --continue`. When I finally get to C I realise the same code must have already been applied and now the patch is empty.

I have the option of `git cherry-pick --allow-empty` but this would leave an empty commit in my history which I don't want. Ideally I'd like to skip just this one patch (C). However there is no `git cherry-pick --skip`. I could `git cherry-pick --abort` but that would lose all my work with A and B.

As a workaround I could accept the empty, remember which one it was and then remove it with a `git rebase -i B` after finishing the cherry-pick. Is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe you could rebase a range of commits instead of the whole branch? A^..B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), "`git cherry-pick/revert`" learned a new "`--skip`" action.

So in your case: **`git cherry-pick --skip` on `C`**.

See [commit dcb500d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dcb500dc16ce8db556b51e9a5b3fa977111d0443), [commit de81ca3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de81ca3f36b0f1db8bd615c98f2a5c819092c275), [commit 265ab48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/265ab48f2646605b27e1343ac50efa9763690f04), [commit 918d1e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/918d1e6ed89738afad63a5cfc92668ac77a7be95), [commit 6a1f904](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a1f9046a40ad69eb00e5a83c6825972113f6e0f) (02 Jul 2019) by [Rohit Ashiwal (`r1walz`)](https://github.com/r1walz).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d97c62c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d97c62c828d6f0eb7ba7067c8c24793620900dd8), 19 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### cherry-pick/revert: add --skip option
>
> `git am` or `rebase` have a `--skip` flag to skip the current commit if the
>   user wishes to do so.
>
> During a `cherry-pick` or `revert` a user could likewise skip a commit, but needs to use '`git reset`' (or in the case of conflicts '`git reset --merge`'), followed by '`gi`t (`cherry-pick` | `revert`) `--continue`' to skip the commit.
>   This is more annoying and sometimes confusing on the users' part.
>
> Add a `--skip` option to make skipping commits easier for the user and to make the commands more consistent.
>
> Update the advice messages, to tell users about this less
>   cumbersome way of skipping commits.

So instead of seeing:

> ```
> Otherwise, please use 'git reset
>
>    If you wish to skip this commit, use:
>
>    git reset
> ```

You will see:

> ```
>  Otherwise, please use 'git cherry-pick --skip
>
>  and then use:
>
>    git cherry-pick --continue
> ```

---

The mechanism to prevent "`git commit`" from making an empty commit or amending during an interrupted cherry-pick was broken during the rewrite of "`git rebase`" in C, which has been corrected with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020).

See [commit 5b7a64d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b7a64df40bec755b0d9ef477764e45ba72abf7b) (06 Dec 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit 430b75f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/430b75f7209c554d88e3554eb54cebf4ba1e4608), [commit 901ba7b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/901ba7b1efe8ba9464aac528ecd46e8dd4f01003), [commit 8d57f75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d57f7574993deb906461d4267373e1c9c733053), [commit 21b11c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21b11c6d1de3840dcaf3fa82dae14ca3924f689f), [commit f028d66](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f028d661c74f29de0e26494e6c9fbcf186b0d4ae), [commit 780308d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/780308d060b2756ed52913ad2c1328c0d7049c05) (06 Dec 2019) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f085189](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f085189f145d1092b43223b72992e851fb412895), 25 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/430b75f7209c554d88e3554eb54cebf4ba1e4608): give correct advice for empty commit during a rebase
>
> <sup>Original-patch-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
>
> In [dcb500dc16c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dcb500dc16ce8db556b51e9a5b3fa977111d0443) ("`cherry-pick/revert`: advise using --skip", 2019-07-02, Git v2.23.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d97c62c828d6f0eb7ba7067c8c24793620900dd8) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c9b961d7eb15fb583a2a812088713a68a85f1c0)), `git commit` learned to suggest to run `git cherry-pick --skip` when trying to cherry-pick an empty patch.
>
> However, it was overlooked that there are more conditions than just a `git cherry-pick` when this advice is printed (which originally suggested the neutral `git reset`): the same can happen during a rebase.
>
> Let's suggest the correct command, even during a rebase.
>
> While at it, we adjust more places in [`builtin/commit.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/430b75f7209c554d88e3554eb54cebf4ba1e4608/builtin/commit.c) that incorrectly assumed that the presence of a `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` meant that surely this must be a `cherry-pick` in progress.
>
> Note: we take pains to handle the situation when a user runs a `git cherry-pick` *during* a rebase.
>   This is quite valid (e.g. in an `exec` line in an interactive rebase).
>   On the other hand, it is not possible to run a rebase during a cherry-pick, meaning: if both `rebase-merge/` and `sequencer/` exist or `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` and `REBASE_HEAD` point to the same commit , we still want to advise to use `git cherry-pick --skip`.

Answer (score 1):

You can quit the cherry-pick in progress with `git  cherry-pick --quit`. After that A and B should be still in your branch and you continue with `git cherry-pick D`.